How can I manage multiple fitebase projects for clients
As an app agency, we want to provide Android, iOS, and web versions of our app to over 100 customers, we aim to customize each platform for them and charge a monthly fee. Can an organization like ours set up accounts for all these customers under different plans and have them billed to our organization? Additionally, is there a limit to the number of customers we can serve with this model?
We would appreciate guidance on this matter.
I looked at the documentation on Firsbase but not clear.


As an app agency we want to provide Android, iOS, and web versions of our app to over 100 customers.

That's perfectly possible, you can create a Firebase project and then create an app for each platform separately.

Can an organization like ours set up accounts for all these customers under different plans and have them billed to our organization?

If your organization needs to create user accounts that can be used later by your customers, then you should consider using the Firebase Admin SDKs. So instead of letting the users authenticate client-side, you can create the users in a managed environment, like a server you control or Cloud Functions.

Can an organization like ours set up accounts for all these customers under different plans and have them billed to our organization?

There is nothing already built-in that allows you to do that. You have to implement your own mechanism to achieve that. If you need to differentiate your users somehow, then I recommend you incorporate custom claims using the Firebase Admin Auth SDK.

Additionally, is there a limit to the number of customers we can serve with this model?

No, there is no limit. You can create as many users as you want.

I'm rather looking ways to manage multiple firebase accounts for my potential clients. I wanted to put all these over 100 apps in one project. But it appears that may not be possible.

Yes, you can create a project for each customer but you won't be able to share the resources, the same databases, and authentication. It's up to you to decide what's best for your project. So can I help you with other information?
